# how can i improve number predictions?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, predict, opencv, python

I've got some number classification model, on test data it works OK, but when I want to classifier other images, I faced with problems that my model can't exactly predict what number is it. Pls, help me improve the model.predict() performance.

I've tried to train my model in many ways, in the code below there is a function that creates classification model, I trained this model actually many ways, [1K < n < 60K] of input test data, [3 < e < 50] of trained iterations.

```py
def load_data():
    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

    train_images = tf.keras.utils.normalize(train_images, axis = 1)
    test_images = tf.keras.utils.normalize(test_images, axis = 1)

    return (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels)

def create_model():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = tf.nn.softmax))

    data = load_data(n=60000, k=5)
    model.compile(optimizer ='adam',
             loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(data[0][0][:n], data[0][1][:n], epochs = e)# ive tried from 3-50 epochs
    model.save(config.model_name)

def load_model():
    return tf.keras.models.load_model(config.model_name)def predict(images):
    try:
        model = load_model()
    except:
        create_model()
        model = load_model()
    images = tf.keras.utils.normalize(images, axis = 0)
    d = load_data()

    plot_many_images([d[0][0][0].reshape((28,28)), images[0]],['data', 'image'])

    predictions = model.predict(images)
    return predictions
```

I think that my input data isn't looking like the data is predicting model, but I've tried to make it as similar as I can. On this pic(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2H01t.jpg) on the LEFT is train data image, and on RIGHT is my parsed image, they are both 28x28 pix, both a cv2.noramalized

for the test image predictions I've used this(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc3Y9.jpg) sudoku, it's already formatted to be similar with a test data numbers, but when I test this image with the model prediction the result is not so nice(https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7G6t.jpg)
As you can see predicted data leaves much to be desired.

P.S. the (' ') items in predicted data result made by my hands(I've replaced numbers at that positions by ' '), cos after predictions they all have some value(1-9), its not necessary now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you mean "on test data it works OK"? if you mean its works good for train data but do not has a good prediction on test data, maybe your model was over-fit in training phase. i suggest to use train/validation/test approach to train your network.